# Populating a Listview with a string from the key of a dictionary, and values from its pair which is a custom object

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am trying to populate a ListView with a dictionary.

What I am trying to do is to display the Key (which is a string) followed by some but not all elements of the value custom object.

For example, my key pair is a

The NameObject is :

public class NameObject

```
{
    public bool Suggested { get; set; }
    public bool Popular { get; set; }
    public string Gender { get; set; }
    public short Personality { get; set; }
    public short Decade { get; set; }
    public string Origin { get; set; }
    public string Diminutives { get; set; }
    public string ShortMeaning { get; set; }
    public string LongMeaning { get; set; }
}
```

What I would like to appear on the listview is an entry for every key pair in the dictionary, key first (which is colored by gender), then ShortMeaning, a star if Popular, and a thumbs up if Suggested.

I'm certain I'll need custom cells, but I'm at a loss for even populating with the key pair info to begin with.

Comment: ItemsSource must be an IEnumerable, and Dictionary is not

Comment: I'm confused why can't you use a list of the class NameObject

Comment: @Scarnet Okay, I'm using the list now, Good catch. I've it in an ObservableCollection but now I need to figure out how to bind properties of the object class in the collection from a different class in to an itemsource and then in xaml. Thanks for your reply.